# <a> onclick causes "is not a function" in FF, but IE ok

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, href

My code below works great in IE8, but in FF 3.5 clicking the link causes an error that "start_upload is not a function".  What is going on?  (Of course start_upload is a valid function that works fine in IE)

```
<div align="left">
  <a href="#" onClick="start_upload();"
    onMouseOver="start_upload.src='/Images/Buttons/Upload-glow.gif'" 
    onMouseOut="start_upload.src='/Images/Buttons/Upload.gif'">
    <img src="/Images/Buttons/Upload.gif" id="start_upload" width="90" height="25" border="0"></a>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `start_upload` a function?

Answer (score 3):

That is because of the way `on....` events are handled, or are standardly supposed to be handled. The context of the `onclick` inline function is the `<a>` element to which it was attached, then its parent, then its parent, so on until `document` and `window`. Since IE supports referencing items by ID (and FF should, but still don't do it) it works. However, it's correct anyways - `start_upload` is not a function. It's an image. What do you intend `start_upload();` to do, exactly? You can set its `src` and that's correct, but you cannot invoke an element as a function.

Comment: but I have defined a javascript function called start_upload higher up in the page. I tried replacing the code with an img tag but get the same error in FF.  See for yourself: http://www.generationd.com/Pages/Private/DownloadUpload/Upload.php

Comment: So don't duplicate it. Change your function `start_upload` to something like `startUpload` and it will work.

Comment: AHHH...now I get it.  I mistakenly name my function the same as the html element.  Ok, thanks!

Comment: Firefox supports referencing elements by bareword ID in quirks mode.  But in any case, this situation is about `document.start_upload` due to the scope chain setup for inline event handlers, so the bareword global scope pollution never even enters the picture.  The real issue is that IE's name lookup in inline event handlers is context-sensitive: `start_upload` resolves to the element but `start_upload()` ignores the element and finds and calls the function.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is that IE is violating the ECMAScript spec.  When you do `start_upload` there it resolves it to either a function or an element depending on whether it's followed by `()` or not.  In Gecko `start_upload` in that situation resolves to the element in all cases, and then you're trying to call an element.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow,your code is running smoothly in Firefox also (assumed that you have define start_upload function). Here is my code which works fine. Also see, you have close `</a>` two times (that should not be a problem).

```
    <body>
    <div align="left">
      <a href="#" onClick="start_upload();"
        onMouseOver="start_upload.src='/Images/Buttons/Upload-glow.gif'" 
        onMouseOut="start_upload.src='/Images/Buttons/Upload.gif'">
 <img src="/Images/Buttons/Upload.gif" id="start_upload" width="90" height="25" border="0">
      </a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script>
    function start_upload()
    {
    alert ("a");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: "Also see, you have close "" two times" - where exactly?

Comment: Just check your posted code, you closed </a> two times. Also did the code I gave worked or giving any errors?

Comment: Sorry, fixed your post - StackOverflow allows you to use simple HTML elements, such as `<a>`, in your posts, so yours was removed.